# basis of neighborhoods of zero in Schwartz Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, schwartz-space

I have the following question:

> In $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and for $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{N}^n $, we defined
>   \begin{align}
> ρ_{\alpha,\beta}(\phi) = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|x^{\alpha}D^{\beta}\phi(x)|.
> \end{align}
>   We defined a distance as follows: we take a bijection $\sigma: \mathbb{N}\mapsto \mathbb{N}^n\times \mathbb{N}^n$, and set
>   \begin{align}
> d(\phi,\varphi) = \sum_n 2^{-n}\frac{ρ_{\sigma(n)}(\phi-\varphi)}{1 + ρ_{\sigma(n)}(\phi − \varphi)}
> \end{align}
>   This distance induces a topology in $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Starting from these definitions, prove that the family of sets
>   \begin{align}
> N_{\epsilon, l, m} = \Big\lbrace \phi\in S\mid \sum_{|\alpha|\leq l, |\beta|\leq m}p_{\alpha, \beta}(\phi)<\epsilon\Big\rbrace
> \end{align}
>   defines a basis of neighborhoods of $0 \in S$.

I know that what we have to do is to assume that we have a open set $U$ in $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ containing zero, that is, for every $x\in U$ there exists a disc
\begin{align}
B_{r,x}=\lbrace \phi\in S\mid d(x,\phi)<r\rbrace 
\end{align}
such that $x\in B_{r,x}\subseteq U$. Then we have to look if there exist some $N_{\epsilon,l,m}$ that defines a basis for $U$. Thats the point I get lost...

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: If you have Rudin's *Functional Analysis* handy, look at 1.38(c) which seems to prove something rather close, albeit with a maximum rather than a sum of seminorms to create the distance function.  Also, you have a typo in your second displayed equation, where $\rho_\sigma(n)$ should be $\rho_{\sigma(n)}$.

Answer (score -1):

Writing the basis distance in base 2, we can see that only the first finite number of digits matter for various basis diameters ($\frac{p}{1+p} \in[0,1)$ and increasing in $p$). Those digits are controlled by the magnitudes of the initial subset of $\{p\}$.